# What to do in such a situation

Tags: phrase-request, questions

I know that phrases like "How to do something" are NOT questions. For example, it's incorrect to ask:

- How to say "Hello" in Chinese?

Let's consider the phrase:

- What to do in such a situation? (I assume that the context is known to listeners)

Is it also NOT a question? What will be a correct question then?
If it IS a question, then why the first phrase is NOT?

Comment: As part of a narrative, it could be understood to mean "What was he/she to do in such a situation?", but of course it's not the right way to ask a question in ordinary conversation.

Comment: ***What to do in such a situation*** is NOT a question, for exactly the same reason *How to do something* isn't. They're ***noun phrases*** (that could "correctly" be used to reference an ***answer*** to the relevant question). The most likely place you'll see one of these "non-questions" is as a ***title / heading*** for some text *which is in fact an "answer"*  (so the title is telling you what follows).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Is the phrase 'What makes work efficient' a noun phrase or a question?

Comment: Consider ***What makes work efficient** is careful preparation* and *I know **what makes work efficient*** . In those sentences, the highlighted text is a noun phrase. But if I ask ***What makes work efficient**?*, that exact same text becomes a "question". Context is everything.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica But a context can't make the phrase 'How to say "Hello" in Chinese' to be a question. So why the phrase 'What makes work efficient' can be either a noun phase or a question depending on the context?

Comment: *So why the phrase 'What makes work efficient' can be either a noun phase or a question depending on the context?* is NOT a valid question in English either! A valid alternative with minimal changes is *So why **is it that** the phrase 'What makes work efficient' can be either a noun phase or a question depending on the context?* To which a big part of the answer is ***What** and **how** are different words, and they don't **always** follow the same syntactic rules*.

Answer (score 1):

Neither phrase is a question. They are correct phrases, and they can function like nouns in sentences:

> Please tell me *how to say "Hello" in Chinese".

> I know *what to do in such a situation*.

Neither phrase is a complete sentence on its own. The verbs "to say" or "to do" are infinitive and English sentences need a finite verb.

The correct question needs a pronoun. I'll use "you"

> What do you do in such a situation.

It is likely that the actual question would be "What should you do..." or "What do you have to do" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

These statements can be questions or declarations. For example:

> How to say "hello" in Chinese: nihao

> How to make a cake: step 1 - add flour and salt to bowl and mix.

The inflection of one's voice in spoken English helps to determine if it's a question.

These statements are also not complete sentences. As a question, these sentences should include an actor or subject: "How do you say "hello" in Chinese?" and "What is one to do in such a situation?"

Likewise, in a question, the subject and the verb often change places, whether or not you're using an interrogative pronoun or adverb (who, what, where, when, why, how). Consider the following:

> Do I have to do this?
> How do I make soup?

Versus

> I do have to do this.
> That's how I make soup*.

*using the adverb *how* usually means you need to explain it further, or you would say "That's how I make gazpacho" without explaining it further because you had already explained it in previous sentences. It's not a phrase that would stand on its own.

Both examples you originally gave are not grammatically correct, but may appear informally. Try to include a **S**ubject, **V**erb, and direct **O**bject in all sentences, and remember that statements are usually **SVO** and questions are usually [interrogative adverb]**VSO**, and that verb is usually a modal or auxiliary verb (do/does/did, can, may, shall, will, would, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

I think both of those sentences can be questions. Frequently, the "How to do something" sentence is used as a paragraph or section header. Similar to newspaper headlines, section headers do not always follow standard grammar and the "How to do something" construction is often interpreted as a declarative statement instead of an interrogative question.

Comment: I think *neither* of those (OP's) sentences can be questions.